# Market quotes and arbitrage argument

Tags: finance, economics, actuarial-science

**DUPLICATE ON HOLD** [Use an arbitrage argument to construct a formula relating the price of the European to the price of an American.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3081031/use-an-arbitrage-argument-to-construct-a-formula-relating-the-price-of-the-europ)

Good day, I wanted to ask for help with a question from one of my exercise sheets.

> For a share S the market quotes a given strike K in both european and
>   american styles. Use an arbitrage argument to construct a formula
>   relating the price of the european to the price of an american.

I do not understand what is meant by EU and US style Market quotes. From my research, it just seems that

- EU is quoted at K USD per share
- US is quoted at $\frac{1}{K}$ shares per 1 USD

But this does not tell me much about applying an arbitrage argument. I have no idea about the formula that relates the two styles.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the way the price is quoted.  The difference between European and American options is that the latter can be exercised at any time (prior to expiry) while the former can only be exercised at expiry.

Comment: We have covered the idea of US vs EU style options but I do not quite see how that can be related to the question

Comment: Really?  The first time you posted this question I wrote the answer out in a comment.  Did you understand what I wrote?

Comment: To be sure:  I'm not entirely clear what the question is after. Without more information, the only thing which holds generally is that the price of the American can not be less than the price of the European.  That's an obvious arbitrage argument.  With more information one might be able to say more.

Comment: It was not me who wrote that question. All you said was that " price of the latter can not exceed the price of the former." i.e. the price of the EU can not exceed the price of the US. Does arbitrage come in as if it were more it would mean free money?

Comment: That I understand. 
Can one not construct a formula relating the two as the question indicates? Something to do with the strike K?

Comment: Of course.  If the American costs less than the European, buy the former and sell the latter.  Then hold both options to expiry.  In all scenarios, you keep the price difference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88624/discussion-between-ypoqou-and-lulu).

Comment: I don't think there's anything further to discuss.  The trivial claim I wrote is the only thing that holds in full generality.  If, say, the underlying is an ordinary non-dividend paying  stock (that can be freely  borrowed at the riskless rate) then the two call options should coincide in price (though not the puts).

Comment: So if US costs less than EU. We buy US and sell EU. This would give a gain. Same way as keeping both options until expiry would give a gain?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "same way", but the first part is right.  Note that this does not work in reverse.  If the US costs more than the EU and you buy the latter and sell the former, you run the risk that the option you are short will be exercised early against you.

Comment: Same way meaning that both cases give a gain.

Comment: There aren't two cases there.  My strategy is very simple:  If the US costs less than the EU I buy the former and sell the latter.  Then, at expiry, the two options either both expire worthless or they are both exercised.  Either way, I get to keep the premium difference.

Comment: Got you. So, to sum up, the call options should coincide in price (but not necessarily the puts). So K=K? Is this the triviality?

Comment: That's not even close to what I wrote.  Please study my comments carefully.

Comment: If we assume the share is ordinary stock (non dividend paying) than what I said is identical to your above comments. 
The strike price is the price at which one can buy or sell the underlying asset, in this case the share. So the call price would be K, no?

Comment: I only used that example to demonstrate that you can't hope to improve on the trivial inequality without more information.  The claim regarding European v American calls on a "normal" underlying is non-trivial and requires a lot of market assumptions.  Nobody said anything about the strike.  Obviously, if one speaks of buying and selling two options the strikes are intended to be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can show this as follows:

Consider two portfolios, $A$ with one American call and $\frac{K}{(1+r)}$ of the riskless asset and $B$ with one American put and one stock.

Unlike European options, you can exercise American options at any moment of time and so your portfolio's value will depend on whether the options are exercised and when they are exercised.

So suppose you exercise your option at some moment $0\leq t \leq T$, then $A$ is worth:

> **$max(S_t,K)*[1+(r*(T-t))]$** at time T;

$B$ is worth

> **$(max(S_t,K)+K*t*r)* r*(T-t)$** at time $T$.

So you can see that $B$ will be more valuable than A at T:

> $(max(S_t,K)+K*t*r) * r*(T-t) \geq max(S_t,K)*[1+(r*(T-t))]$

Note that at time $t = 0$, then

> $American\ Call (0) + K(0) \geq American\ Put (0) + S(0)$

Now, consider $T=t$. Then, the above formulas become:

Portfolio $A$  = $max(S_t,0)$

Portfolio $B$ = $(max(S_t,K)+K*t*r) * r*(T-t) = 0.$

At time $T=t$, then

> $American\ Put + S(0) \geq American\ Call + K^*$

You can combine the two cases as:

> $S(0)-K \leq American\ Call - American\ Put \leq S(0)-K^*$

Now, by no arbitrage, the put-call parity for European options holds:

$S(0)+P(0)=C(0)+K^*$. Then if you rearrange $S(0)-K^*=C(0)-P(0)$.

Then you get a formula relating European and American options that is:

> $S(0)-K \leq American\ Call - American\ Put \leq European\ Call - European\ Put$